# Numpad view not working properly

Tags: axis

This is making me go nuts. Whenever I'm trying to go to the numpad view, instead of going into the 2D and showing only 2 axis, it's trying to show and think about the depth of the third axis.
This is how it should look: [image] This is how it looks instead: [image] Please help me, it has been bothering me for a while but I can't even find anywhere how to fix this (oh also the background isn't full of cubes either.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You are in Perspective view. 
Hit <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to switch to Ortographic.

*Perspective* - all the horizontal lines appear to converge into a vanishing point in the middle of the horizon: the point of view is a... point

*Ortographic* - all the horizontal lines appear as points: the point of view can be thought of as an infinite plane